# Can I force my laptop to recognize its HDMI port?

Tags: display, graphics, hdmi

I have an HP Zenbook Power G9 with Ubuntu, which comes with an HDMI port.
My issue is that this port does not work. When I plug the cable into it, nothing happens and the extra screen stays black.

Screen and cable work, I tested them with a different laptop. They also work if I plug the HDMI cable into the USB-C port through and adapter.

I have tried updating the NVidia drivers and Linux Kernel, but to no avail.
Strangely, the HDMI port is not even listed by `xrandr`:

```
eDP-1 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
   1920x1080     60.02*+  40.02  
   1680x1050     60.02  
   1400x1050     60.02  
   1600x900      60.02  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1400x900      60.02  
   1280x960      60.02  
   1440x810      60.02  
   1368x768      60.02  
   1280x800      60.02  
   1280x720      60.02  
   1024x768      60.02  
   960x720       60.02  
   928x696       60.02  
   896x672       60.02  
   1024x576      60.02  
   960x600       60.02  
   960x540       60.02  
   800x600       60.02  
   840x525       60.02  
   864x486       60.02  
   700x525       60.02  
   800x450       60.02  
   640x512       60.02  
   700x450       60.02  
   640x480       60.02  
   720x405       60.02  
   684x384       60.02  
   640x360       60.02  
   512x384       60.02  
   512x288       60.02  
   480x270       60.02  
   400x300       60.02  
   432x243       60.02  
   320x240       60.02  
   360x202       60.02  
   320x180       60.02  
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

What could I try next?

Comment: Does Windows detect it?

Comment: I just checked to be sure (it's a dual boot machine) and also windows does not detect it.

Comment: Looks like a HW failure then. Maybe the HDMI module got loose.

Comment: From further investigation I could find that some other people online report having the same or similar issues with HP laptops. Furthermore, I got access to another laptop, identical model, that has the same exact problem. Unfortunately I have not found a solution yet.
Thanks for your time anyways, Artem.

Comment: You're welcome. If your warranty hasn't expired, you know what to do - RMA it. If many people are affected, a class action lawsuit could be filed I guess.

Comment: I've read somewhere a BIOS update can rectify this - assuming there is one of course

Comment: Thanks for the input @JaromandaX, I have tried the BIOS update route, unfortunately it still does not work